# Multiple Windows in PyQt4

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt4

I have a PyQt program used to visualize some python objects. I would like to do display multiple objects, each in its own window.

What is the best way to achieve multi-window applications in PyQt4?

Currently I have the following:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    windowList = []

    def __init__(self, animal):
        pass

    def addwindow(self, animal)
        win = MainWindow(animal)
        windowList.append(win)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = QMainWindow(dog)
    win.addWindow(fish)
    win.addWindow(cat)

    app.exec_()
```

However, this approach is not satisfactory, as I am facing problems when I try to factor out the MultipleWindows part in its own class. For example:

```
class MultiWindows(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    windowList = []

    def __init__(self, param):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def addwindow(self, param)
        win = MainWindow(param) # How to call the initializer of the subclass from here?
        windowList.append(win)

class PlanetApp(MultiWindows):
    def __init__(self, planet):
        pass

class AnimalApp(MultiWindows):
    def __init__(self, planet):
        pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = PlanetApp(mercury)
    win.addWindow(venus)
    win.addWindow(jupiter)

    app.exec_()
```

The above code will call the initializer of the MainWindow class, rather than that of the appropriate subclass, and will thus throw an exception.

How can I call the initializer of the subclass? Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not using dialogs? In Qt you do not need to use the main window unless you want to use docks etc.. Using dialogs will have the same effect.

I can also see a problem in your logic regarding the fact that you want your super class to be calling the constructor of its children, which of course can be any type. I recommend you rewrite it like the following:

```
class MultiWindows(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, param):
        self.__windows = []

    def addwindow(self, window):
        self.__windows.append(window)

    def show():
        for current_child_window in self.__windows:
             current_child_window.exec_() # probably show will do the same trick

class PlanetApp(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, planet):
       QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
       # do cool stuff here

class AnimalApp(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, animal):
       QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
       # do cool stuff here

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys # really need this here??

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    jupiter = PlanetApp(None, "jupiter")
    venus = PlanetApp(None, "venus")
    windows = MultiWindows()
    windows.addWindow(jupiter)
    windows.addWindow(venus)

    windows.show()
    app.exec_()
```

It is not a nice idea to expect the super class to know the parameter to be used in the **init** of its subclasses since it is really hard to ensure that all the constructor will be the same (maybe the animal dialog/window takes diff parameters).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference the subclass that is inheriting the super-class from inside the super-class, I am using `self.__class__()`, so the MultiWindows class now reads:

```
class MultiWindows(QtGui.QMainWindow):
windowList = []

def __init__(self, param):
    raise NotImplementedError()

def addwindow(self, param)
    win = self.__class__(param)
    windowList.append(win)
```